# Can't get DD-MM-YYYY date format in Vuejs from mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, vue.js, vue-component

Hey I receive `dateCreated` (the date when the account was created) and I can't find how to set it to DD-MM-YYYY.

In my Vue page the code is:

[image]

The problem is that the website shows me the date in this format:

[image]

But I really don't want **YYYY-MM-DD T HH-MM-SS-SSS**. I just want **DD-MM-YYYY**.  Here this is mysql column of `dateCreated`:

[image]

Would really appreciate help, thanks

Comment: Hey, this is not working. I'm not sure about where am I supposed to c/p "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(dateCreated, "%d/%m/%Y"); "

Comment: That goes wherever you are making your SQL query.  For example:  `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(dateCreated, "%d/%m/%Y") AS dateCreated FROM table`.  If you don't have access to the database, then you should use the Vue portion of the solution

Comment: This don't change anything.. `var dateFormat = 'SELECT DATE_FORMAT(dateCreated, "%d/%m/%Y") AS dateCreated FROM users WHERE id = '+idUser;`

Comment: Can you show all of your JavaScript code for the request/response?  Maybe it's reformatting it when you store the result in JavaScript.  [Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e5d7e7d/2) is how that statement returns data from MySQL

Comment: This is the entire js code. I use this one to get all the infos of a profile by getting the id of this specific user   `exports.getOneUser = (req, res, next) => {
  const idUser = encodeURI(req.params.userId);
  var sqlAllFromMembre = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE id ='+idUser;
  var dateFormat = 'SELECT DATE_FORMAT(dateCreated, "%d/%m/%Y") AS dateCreated FROM users WHERE id = '+idUser;`

Comment: `mysqlConnection.query(sqlAllFromMembre, dateFormat, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    } else { 
      res.status(200).json(result);  
    }
  });

}`

Comment: You're still using the `SELECT * FROM` query.  You have to use `dateFormat` instead of `sqlAllFromMembre`, and you also have to name each field individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could format it in MySQL:

```sql
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(dateCreated, "%d-%m-%Y") AS dateCreated
```

Or you could use a Vue computed:

```js
computed: {
  formatted() {
    const myDate = this.membre.dateCreated;
    const formatted = ('0' + myDate.getDate()).slice(-2) + '/'
             + ('0' + (myDate.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + '/'
             + myDate.getFullYear();
    return formatted;
  }
}
```